# Inserting a text file between 2 headings

Tags: awk, sed

I was using this to replace and insert text between `! Heading 1` and `! Heading 2`, Was working previously.

Have I done something wrong here?

```
value=`cat sample3`
echo "$value"
# remove chars between headings
sed '/! Heading 1,/! Heading 2/{//p;d;}' $file.txt > file-trimmed.txt

# insert value between the 2 headings
awk -v value="$value" '
$0 == "! Heading 1" {
replace = 1
print
next
}
$0 == "! Heading 2" {
replace = 0
print
next
}
replace {
sub(/^..../, value)
}
{ print }
' file-trimmed.txt > file-mod.txt
```

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in form of code(keep it up). Please do post samples of input and expected output too in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: The sample3 file, is just various urls. and when inserted. Nothing is entered so ! Heading 1 and ! Heading 2 has nothing in between them.

Comment: We need you to not just describe attributes of your data but provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrate your problem and give us something we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with. Without that fewer people will be willing to guess at a solution and they're more likely to get it wrong. See [ask] if that's not clear. You don't need sed when you're using awk btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/! Heading 1/{p;r sample3' -e ':a;N;/! Heading 2/!s/\n//;ta;D}' file
```

If a line contains `! Heading 1`, print it and then print the contents of `sample3`.

Then gather up any lines (reducing those lines to a single line) until another  line containing `! Heading 2` and delete the collected lines i.e. the first of two.

An alternative perhaps more elegant solution:

```
sed -ne '/! Heading 1/{p;r sample3' -e ':a;n;/! Heading 2/!ba};p' file
```